# Order by the max value in the group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

I would like to group my results by one column (NAME), then order by a second column (NOTE) for each group, and finally order the groups by the highest NOTE they have.

So, if my entities are scrambled like these:

```
NAME         NOTE
Andrew       19
Thomas       18
Andrew       18
Andrew       17
Frank        16 
Frank        15
Thomas       14 
Thomas       12
Frank        5
```

I would like them to be ordered like this:

```
NAME         NOTE
Andrew       19
Andrew       18
Andrew       17
Thomas       18
Thomas       14 
Thomas       12
Frank        16 
Frank        15
Frank        5
```

grouped by name, with Andrew appearing first because his highest note is 19, then Thomas (18) and Frank (16).

Regards,

Val

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it using window functions:

```
select name, note
from (select t.*, max(note) over (partition by name) as maxnote
      from t
     ) t
order by maxnote desc, name
```

In addition to ordering by the maxnote, it also orders by the name.  If there are ties, then it keeps all the records for a given name together.

Comment: +1 You can refer to an alias afer `order by`, so no need for the subquery

Comment: @Andomar . . . If it were written that way, then `maxnote` would have to be in the output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nice, the maxnote in the order by should have `desc` after it, but nice solution.

Comment: @Valerio Volga - The note column is not ordered descending with this solution, if you shuffle the test values and run this query there is no ordering of the note within the name partitions.

Answer (score 3):

CTE answer...

```
Create  Table NameNoteTable (Name Varchar(10), Note Int);

Insert  NameNoteTable
Select  'Andrew', 19
Union   All
Select  'Andrew', 18
Union   All
Select  'Andrew', 17
Union   All
Select  'Thomas', 18
Union   All
Select  'Thomas', 14
Union   All
Select  'Thomas', 12
Union   All
Select  'Frank', 16
Union   All
Select  'Frank', 15;

With    cte As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By Max(Note) Desc) As tID,
                Name,
                Max(Note) As MaxNote
        From    NameNoteTable
        Group   By Name
)
Select  nnt.Name, nnt.Note
From    NameNoteTable nnt
Join    cte c
        On  nnt.Name = c.Name
Order   By tID, Note Desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.name, t.note
FROM @tbl t
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(note) FROM @tbl WHERE name = t.name) DESC
        , name
        , note DESC
```

This is the simplest way, using PARTITION BY is only slightly more syntax and on larger tables would likely run more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way:

select name, note from NameNoteTable
order by name asc, note desc

Comment: This query orders the `name` column alphabetically. In the question, the `name` column should be ordered based on the descending order of `note` per user